# How to populate multiple report fields with same data? MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

Wise IT community

I have a query where some fields are filled in with valid data, and then blanks.
This is in itself not a problem.
The issue comes when i want one field from the query to fill multiple fields in a report with the same data.

Tbl 1 = TB_Short_Title.
This table only contains Master data for each row in the query result
TB_Short_Title!Short_Title = Primary Key

| Id | Short_Title | Supersessionrate | Supersession_Interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Short-Title 1 | 12 | ww |
| 2 | Short-Title 2 | 6 | m |
| 3 | Short-Title 3 | 12 | m |
| 4 | Short-Title 4 | 1 | m |

Supersessionrate and Supersession_Interval is used to calculate the next ED_Start_Date and ED_Expirier_Date

Upon creating the first edition to a short title user will be promted to enter a Eddition_Txt and first ED_Start_Date with following VBA:
Note: the VBA contains code to insert edditions, add next edition and calculate ED_Start_Date and ED_Expirier_Date automaticly.

```
    Function Ammend_ED(EditionCount As Integer)

Dim FirstEdition As Long
Dim FirstEditionText As String
Dim LastEdition As Long
Dim LastEditionText As String
Dim NewEd   As String
Dim varTotal As Integer
Dim NewKey  As Long
Dim NewDate As Variant


Me.AllowEdits = True
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

If EditionCount <> 0 Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
    FirstEdition = Me.Eddition.Value
End If

If EditionCount <> 0 Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast
    LastEdition = Me.Eddition.Value
End If

Me.AllowAdditions = True
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

NewEd = UCase(InputBox("Enter new edition", "New Eddition"))

If NewEd <> "" Then
    NewKey = Nz(DLookup("ID_Key", "TB_Eddition_Aide", "Edditions_Txt = '" & NewEd & "'"))
    
    If FirstEdition <> 0 Then
        FirstEdition = FirstEdition - 1
        LastEdition = LastEdition + 1
        
        If FirstEdition < 1 Then
         
            If NewKey < FirstEdition Or NewKey > LastEdition Then
                FirstEditionText = Nz(DLookup("Edditions_Txt", "TB_Eddition_Aide", "ID_Key = " & FirstEdition))
                LastEditionText = Nz(DLookup("Edditions_Txt", "TB_Eddition_Aide", "ID_Key = " & LastEdition))
                MsgBox "Edition " & NewEd & " is not allowed " & vbCrLf & _
                "Allowed edition is: " & LastEditionText
                
                Exit Function
            End If
            
        Else
            
            If NewKey < FirstEdition Or NewKey > LastEdition Then
                
                FirstEditionText = Nz(DLookup("Edditions_Txt", "TB_Eddition_Aide", "ID_Key = " & FirstEdition))
                LastEditionText = Nz(DLookup("Edditions_Txt", "TB_Eddition_Aide", "ID_Key = " & LastEdition))
                MsgBox "Edition " & NewEd & " is not allowed " & vbCrLf & _
                "Allowed editions are: " & FirstEditionText & " or " & LastEditionText
                
                Me.AllowAdditions = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    End If
        
    Me.Eddition = NewKey
        
    If NewKey > 0 Then
        NewDate = InputBox("Enter first Start Date", "First Effective Date", Date)
        
        If StrPtr(NewDate) = 0 Then
            Me.AllowAdditions = False
            Me.AllowDeletions = True
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
            Me.AllowDeletions = False
        End If
        
        If NewDate > 0 Then
            
            If IsDate(NewDate) Then
                Me!ED_Start_Date.Value = CDate(NewDate)
                Me.Dirty = False
                NewExpDate = DateAdd(Supersession_Interval, Supersessionrate, NewDate) - 1
                Me.ED_Expirier_Date = NewExpDate
                DoCmd.SetOrderBy "Eddition ASC,"
                
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If


DoCmd.Save
DoCmd.SetWarnings True


End Function
```

Tbl2 2 = TB_Edditions
This table contains every edition of key that each short title have.
this table contains data like, ED_Start_Date as date, ED_Expirier_Date as date, Eddition as integer
TB_Edditions!Id = Primary key (Autonumber)

The relation is:
1 TB_Short_Title!Short_Title to
Many TB_Edditions!Short_Title

| Id | Short_Title | Eddition | ED_Star_Date | ED_Expirier_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Short-Title 1 | Q | 27-05-2021 | 10-11-2021 |
| 2 | Short-Title 3 | A | 01-07-2021 | 30-06-2022 |
| 3 | Short-Title 4 | A | 01-07-2021 | 31-07-2021 |
| 4 | Short-Title 4 | B | 01-08-2021 | 31-08-2021 |
| 5 | Short-Title 4 | C | 01-09-2021 | 30-09-2021 |
| 6 | Short-Title 4 | D | 01-10-2021 | 30-10-2021 |
| 7 | Short-Title 2 | AC | 01-07-2021 | 31-12-2021 |
| 8 | Short-Title 1 | R | 11-11-2021 | 02-02-2022 |

Tbl 3 = TB_Eddition_Aide
a constant table that provides an Eddition_Id as integer and a Eddition_Txt as string. the table runs from a until zz in numeric order (a=1, b=2,... zz=18278)

Relation is:
1 TB_Eddition_Aide!ID_Key to
Many TB_Edditions!Eddition

TB_Eddition_Aide!ID_Key = Primary key

| ID_Key | Eddition_Txt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 17 | Q |
| 18 | R |
| 29 | AC |

Also

Query result:

| Short_Title | apr | maj | jun | jul | aug | sep | okt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Short-Title 1 |  | Q |  |  | R |  |  |
| Short-Title 2 |  |  |  | AC |  |  |  |
| Short-Title 3 |  |  |  | A |  |  |  |
| Short-Title 4 |  |  |  | A | B | C | D |

The SQL for the query is:

```
TRANSFORM First(TB_Eddition_Aide.Edditions_Txt) Edditions_Txt
SELECT TB_Edditions.Short_Title
FROM TB_Eddition_Aide INNER JOIN TB_Edditions ON TB_Eddition_Aide.ID_Key = 
TB_Edditions.Eddition
WHERE (((TB_Edditions.ED_Start_Date)>DateSerial([From APR of what year?],3,1)))
GROUP BY TB_Edditions.Short_Title
PIVOT Format([ED_Start_Date],"mmm") In ("apr","maj","jun","jul","aug","sep","okt");
```

I want to be able to generate a report that fills in the blank fields with the last known value until a new edition is effective.
I.E. if we look at the one called AKAD 101009, it states that edition "Q" is in effect first time in May, and the next edition is in effect from Aug.
The report should display edition Q for May, Jun, Jul.

There is a query like this one, covering the months okt - apr, this query covers a year change. I imagien that it will be the same procedure to get this query to work, as all data is sorted by dates.

The aim is to either create a query that never returns a blank value and is able to differentiate that every short title may have edition change at different intervals (1 month, 2 monthe, 3 months etc.. all the way up to 60 weeks)

Comment: Edit question to show sample raw data as text table, not image. I expect this issue will require a VBA custom function.

Comment: @ June7
New format edited like table.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the **raw** data that goes towards making the expected outcome - this gives anybody working on an answer for you something to use. Also, what about the other months in the year (Jan-Mar and Nov/Dec)?

Comment: @Applecore is this the thing you wanted?
i am pretty new to this sort of ting, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: No, please post the actual raw data that is used to create the output - this allows us to copy and paste into a set of tables to check that any answer provided works before posting.

Comment: @Applecore i have now included all the data for the 3 tables that provide data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the way to do this is to use a custom VBA function that returns the correct information to the query. I've created the following that works:

```
Public Function fGetEditionText(lngEditionID As Long, lngMonth As Long, lngYear As Long) As String
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Const JetDateFmt = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#;;;\N\u\l\l"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT EA.Eddition_Txt " _
        & " FROM (TB_Short_Title AS T INNER JOIN TB_Edditions AS E ON T.Short_Title=E.Short_Title) " _
        & " INNER JOIN TB_Eddition_Aide AS EA ON EA.ID_Key=E.Eddition " _
        & " WHERE T.ID=" & lngEditionID _
        & " AND E.ED_Start_Date>=" & Format(DateSerial(lngYear, 4, 1), JetDateFmt) _
        & " AND E.ED_Start_Date<=" & Format(DateSerial(lngYear, lngMonth + 1, 0), JetDateFmt) _
        & " ORDER BY E.ED_Start_Date DESC;"
    Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rsData.BOF And rsData.EOF) Then
        fGetEditionText = rsData!Eddition_Txt
    End If
fExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "fGetEditionText", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume fExit
End Function
```

You can then create a query that returns the values you expect:

```
SELECT TB_Short_Title.Short_Title, 
fGetEditionText(ID,4,2021) AS Apr,
fGetEditionText(ID,5,2021) AS May,
fGetEditionText(ID,6,2021) AS Jun,
fGetEditionText(ID,7,2021) AS Jul,
fGetEditionText(ID,8,2021) AS Aug,
fGetEditionText(ID,9,2021) AS Sep,
fGetEditionText(ID,10,2021) AS Oct
FROM TB_Short_Title;
```

This returns:
[image]

In your sample data, you had "Short-Title 1" with a start date of 11 November 2021 for Edition R, but you are showing this starting in August in your expected output.

You are using "Short_Title" as the foreign key in `TB_Edditions` - it is normal to use the primary key from `TB_Short_Title` instead.

In order for this query to be flexible, I would suggest that you use VBA to update the `.SQL` of this query with the required year.

Comment: I found the error :) A missing "T" in "Start" :)

Now i get a return query, but it only displays the ID number (Integer) of the edition.
What am i doing wrong to get an other result than you?

Comment: Start by putting a `Debug.Print strSQL` on the line before `Set rsData=db.OpenRecordset` and have a look at the SQL that is being created.

Comment: The SQL string looks fine. But the fGetEditionText returns a integer and not a string (letter)
In the TB_Edditions, the edition value is a integer derived from the TB_Eddition_Aide.
Is there any way to conver that integer value to the corrosponding string value from TB_Eddition_Aide!Eddition_Txt?

Comment: You need to modify the SQL string that is created to include a join to the relevant table - this information was not indicated in your original post, which had `TB_Edditions!Eddition` as text.

Comment: I am not that strong in SQL, i am sorry it was not clear that the edition in TB_Eddition!Eddition was integer. Any way you can help?

Comment: Modified to include a join to get the actual text - in your sample data you do not have a value for "D".

Comment: You my god man is a true wizard in the programming world :)
I humbly thank you for your help.

Comment: Quick qustion.
How can I ensure that when I use the code you made, i will display an edition that is covering a change of year?
Say, i have a key where ED_Start_Date is 12-01-2021 and ED_Expirier_Date is 01-31-2022?
At the moment it will not take keys that is covering the change of year.